# How can i replace words in a string using an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I am trying to search a string and replace all instances of a certain string with another other string every time the first string appears.

My goal is to avoid using many preg-replace statements and to make an array which is easily editable and maintainable, containing keys that are identical to the words i'm looking to replace and values containing the replacements.

So far I've got something like this:

```php
$colors = array('red' => 'i am the color red', 'blue' => 'hi I am       blue',);

$string = "red, blue, red, and lots of blue";
foreach($colors as $key => $value) {
    preg_replace($key, $value, $string);
    echo $string;
}
```

This is not yet working.

Comment: well, there's the syntax error in your array definition, for one. this code wouldn't even compile, let alone run.

Comment: Advantage of regex here might be the use of [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) or to do [caseless matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). You need to enclose your pattern into [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `'/pattern/flags'`. For casless use `i` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). [See your updated demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/505319)

Comment: Perhaps - if you still remember - you could share in which kind it was not working. e.g. what went wrong or how it appeared incomplete. What were the error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing straight string replacement (no regular expressions) so use:

```
$string = str_replace(array_keys($colors), $colors, $string);
```

No loop needed, `str_replace()` takes arrays.

FYI: In your code, aside from the parse error, you aren't assigning the return of the `preg_replace()` back to a string to be used and regex using a specific a pattern with delimiters and special syntax.  You need word boundaries `\b` as well to keep from replacing the `red` in `redefine` and `undelivered` etc.:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\b$key\b/", $value, $string);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I chose this answer because it is the most helpful and indepth and  does what i need without the loop. Thank you to everyone who submitted an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$colors = array('red' => 'i am the color red', 'blue' => 'hi Im blue');
$string = "red, blue, red, and lots of blue";
foreach($colors as $key => $value) {
    $string = str_replace($key, $value, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

use the above code to get your expected result.

Comment: Why loop when using str_replace()?

Comment: thank you very much for the helpful answer though i chose Abras answer because it forgot about the loop and seems to have the same result

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

echo str-replace($key, $value, $string);